# geom_bar not showing every values

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, geom-bar

I want to draw a bar plot, with `ggplot` and `geom_bar`, but it seems that the behavior of `geom_bar` is not consistent. I don't understand why.

My data is a time series of precipitations:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(42)
dt1 <- data.table(dateHeure=seq(ymd_hms("2014-06-04 13:30:00"), 
                ymd_hms("2014-10-20 08:30:00"), by='1 hour'),
     rain=sample(c(rep(5,15), rep(10,15), rep(20,10), 
             rep(30, 5), 40, rep(0, 3262))))
```

Then i plot it, and not all the data appears... Why is some data missing?

```
ggplot(data=dt1)+
geom_bar(aes(x=dateHeure, y=rain),        
      stat="identity", 
      fill="blue")  # doesn't work!
```

[image: wrong plot]

But if i add the variable `color` in `aes`, then the plot is correct!

```
 ggplot(data=dt1)+
geom_bar(aes(x=dateHeure, y=rain, color="rain"),     
 stat="identity",
 width=0.2)  # work properly
```

[image: ok_plot]

So someone know why `geom_bar` doesn't work properly without `color`? Because i can't rely on it if sometimes not all the data is correctly plotted...

thanks!

**edit:** to respond to @eipi10, i added the plots. The strange thing is that when i resize the plot window in the first case, the data which is plotted changes!

Comment: I might make this question even more interesting. Try: `ggplot(dt1, aes(x=dateHeure, y=rain)) + geom_line()` and compare results to your supposedly "work properly" example.

Comment: In this very particular case, `geom_line` and `geom_bar` look the same, but i don't know what do you mean?

Comment: When I run your code on my computer, the two plots look exactly the same to me, except for the colour.

Comment: So i don't understand why it's not the case on mine :-) i tried on a clean session, but still not working for me. I hoped that someone here would have had the same problem... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the edit to your question, I think I know what's happening: In the first plot, you use `fill="blue"`. But the bin widths are very small compared to the overall range of the x-axis. This results in very, very thin vertical bars--so thin that you can't see some of them on your screen, but they appear when you expand the physical width of the plot.

On the other hand, in your second plot you used `colour="rain"`, which adds a border to each bar, making each bar thicker, so they are visible, even when the physical width of the plot is relatively small.

Try adding `colour="blue"`(or "red" or whatever) to your first plot and I think you'll see all the bars, even without resizing. On the other hand, try changing `colour="rain"` to `fill="rain"` on your second plot and see if that creates the "disappearing data" effect on your second plot.

**UPDATE:** In response to your comment, you can use the colour parameter and then set the line width to get exactly the bar thickness you want, so you don't really need `fill`. For example:

```
ggplot(data=dt1)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=dateHeure, y=rain),        
           stat="identity",
           colour="blue", lwd=0.5)
```

Just set `lwd` (line width) to a value that gives you the bar-width you want. And, of course, you can also change the colour as well.

Comment: Yes, when `colour` is added, inside or outside `aes`, the plot is good. I hoped, for some reason, that it could be ok without adding this `colour` parameter. but I think you're right with the "too thin data to appear on the screen".  If i replace `colour` by `fill`, all the data disappear.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 for your time, i'll accept your answer. One last question: to your opinion,  why does the "incorrect" plot appears right on your computer?It should be too thin too, no?

Comment: I thinks it's just a matter of how large your plot window happens to be at the time and your screen resolution. I happened to have a large enough plot window to see all the vertical lines.

Comment: @eipi10
Many thanks for the detailed and clear explanation.